# How to deal with NA values with different labels

Tags: r, label, na

I am having a problem dealing with NA values from a survey dataset.

```
library(haven)
x <- labelled(
  c(1:3, tagged_na("a", "c", "z"), 4:1),
  c("Agreement" = 1, "Disagreement" = 4, 
    "First" = tagged_na("c"),
    "Refused" = tagged_na("a"), 
    "Not home" = tagged_na("z"))
)
```

Here is the output

```
<Labelled double>
 [1]     1     2     3 NA(a) NA(c) NA(z)     4     3     2     1

Labels:
 value        label
     1    Agreement
     4 Disagreement
 NA(c)        First
 NA(a)      Refused
 NA(z)     Not home
```

What I want is to calculate how many NA(c), NA(a), and NA(z) individually, not as a whole. And I would like to subset data based on NA(c), NA(a), and NA(z). How can I do this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output? `is.na(x)` gives you the position of `NA` values.

Comment: I would like to see something like this: NA(a):1  NA(c):1  NA(z) :1.

Comment: @MZ2017 is my answer safies your need?

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
base::table(haven::as_factor(x, levels = "labels"))
```

**output**

```
Agreement Disagreement        First 
       2            1            1 
 Refused     Not home 
       1            1
```

Comment: Thanks! Did you use any package? I tried to run your code, but I got "Error in factor(x, levs, labels = labs, ordered = ordered) : invalid 'labels'; length 5 should be 1 or 2"

Comment: @MZ2017 it's haven. the one you are using. Updated my answer to add package. Pls check now.

Comment: I don't why, I still get an error message. Maybe it has something to do with my R studio environment. But I am able to use as_factor(x) command to change the label to factor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We could use `get_values` function from `sjlabelled` package, extract value which have `NA` in them and use `table` to get their count.

```
table(grep('NA', sjlabelled::get_values(x), value = TRUE))

# NA(a) NA(c) NA(z) 
#    1     1     1
```